# How to sort a table by FirstName in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and I'm just trying to sort this table by First Name but I'm not really sure where to start.

Here's the controller which simply renders the data on the table.

```
    $resultArray = object_to_array($result);

    return view('home', [
        'resultArray' => $resultArray
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're likely paginating the data, you wouldn't really want to sort on the front end, otherwise you'll just be ordering the results from the first 50 results into an order sorted alphabetically.

Instead you'd do something like

```
$users = User::orderBy('firstName')->paginate(50)
```

Then passing users to your view.

At the moment, it looks like you're converting the resulting data into an array, which isn't really necessary, as laravel returns a collection object which has some nice features which [wrap some functional programming features](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html), such as sort.

**Edit:**

If you just want to order your data in the way its currently presented in your example, the best way would be with usort. This doesn't have the advantages of the laravel collection, but would still allow you to sort the array as you wanted.

If you have the data:

```
$items = [
    ['name' => 'barry'], 
    ['name' => 'alan']
];

usort($items, function ($a, $b) { return $a['name'] > $b['name'];});
```

Would reorder the array to be

```
$items = [
    ['name' => 'alan'],
    ['name' => 'barry'] 
];
```

It's passed by reference though, so the original will be modified.

I would recommend looking at the laravel collection class though, it provides a much nicer interface for dealing with this kind of data.

Comment: why did you put 50 in the parenthesizes?

Comment: @progx That's the number of items per page. You can pick any number.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just uploaded a new picture which represents the array that renders the data on the table as well as the code that is in my controller that finally renders the data. Can you please take a look at it and let me know how I can sort the FirstName data in the controller? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you just want to order your data in the way its currently presented in your example, the best way would be with usort.

Answer (score 0):

try to sort the name where you get the result array.
means if you are getting it from the database then sort the result by the name in your query.